# MarkLogic search REST api with transform-results metadata-snippet doesn't work with json request

Tags: marklogic

The following json request to the search api gives a search result without the requested transformation:

```
{
  "search": {    
    "qtext": "some query",
    "options": {
      "term": { "apply": "term", "term-option": ["lang=nl"] },
      "transform-results": {
        "apply": "metadata-snippet",
        "preferred-elements": [ { "name": "title", "ns": "" } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When doing the same call as a xml request I get the requested metadata-snippet transformation:

```
<search xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">  
  <qtext>some query</qtext>
  <options>
    <term apply="term">
        <term-option>lang=nl</term-option>
    </term>
    <transform-results  apply="metadata-snippet">
        <preferred-elements>
            <element name="title" ns=''/>
        </preferred-elements>
    </transform-results>
  </options>
</search>
```

What's wrong with my json?

Complete request info:

```
POST /v1/search HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8003
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "search": { "qtext": "some query", "options": { "term": { "apply": "term", "term-option": ["lang=nl"] }, "transform-results": { "apply": "metadata-snippet", "preferred-elements": [ { "name": "title", "ns": "" } ] } } } }
```

Comment: Is the underlying dataset XML or JSON? I'm seeing the same problem but I want to make sure I understand your case.

Comment: Just tested with XML and JSON docs. I'm going to file this as a bug.

Comment: So is this a confirmed bug?

Comment: Not yet, but it's clearly you'll need a different approach. I've usually relied on the built-in snippeting functionality, but take a look at [Customize Search Snippets](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_10158) for ideas on ways to set it up the way you'd like.

Comment: Also, if you know that you'd want the title element (for example), consider using [extract-metadata](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixa#id_41417), which returns that element from each result.

Comment: The extract-metadata works, except that I have title elements on several levels in the document and I only need the top one.

Answer (score 1):

The `metadata-snippet` looks for elements in document properties. Are you sure the title is in there? If it is in the document itself, use `snippet` instead of `metadata-snippet`.

HTH!

Comment: For more detail, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_36346 and http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixa#id_48012

Comment: The title is in the document itself. But when I use the xml request then I get the title info.

Comment: Maybe response to the JSON request is the correct one, and that for the XML one wrong. Did you try using `snippet` instead of `metadata-snippet`?

Comment: Snippet and raw work correctly on both xml and json requests.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment discussion (needed formatting). Since you want to specify just some titles, I suggest path-based constraint, then use  to get those with your result. You will need a path range index for this approach.

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <extract-metadata>
    <constraint-value ref="title"/>
  </extract-metadata> 
  <constraint name="title">
    <range type="xs:string" facet="false">
      <path-index xmlns:my="http://example.com">
        /root/my:title
      </path-index>
    </range>
  </constraint>
</options>
```

If that doesn't work, the next alternative to explore would be a [search response transformation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_94556), but I'd expect this to be simper.